# Concat videos without shifting audio

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a few videos I'm concating with `ffmpeg -f concat -i myfiles.txt -c copy`, and two of the videos in the middle have no audio track. After concat the audio shifts. It moves the audio from later videos on top of the muted ones.

How can I concat without shifting the audio, so the muted parts are still muted?

`audiovideo + audiovideo + audiovideo + video + video + audiovideo + audiovideo`

Comment: You'll have to attach dummy audio to those videos by adding `-f lavfi -i anullsrc`

Comment: and also `-shortest`